# Ideas to nullify the gravity of a Neutron Star?

Tags: science-based, magic, science-fiction

**Hello everyone!**

I've been sitting here for the past hour extensively rewriting a setting because I ran into an issue with mapping. I had a setting built off the good 'ol concept of a dyson sphere world. By this I specifically mean, a world on the inside of a dyson sphere, similar to an inverted world. But when I was mapping the size of the world it got out of hand, even using a blue dwarf or similarly "minimal sized star". The sphere encompassing the star was just beyond the realms of reasonable for the size of world I want to work with, as I plan on detailing much of the land masses.

So I'm kicking around the idea of using a neutron, pulsar, or magnetar as the size of those work perfectly for what I have planned. I have figured out a way to explain away the whole radiation killing everything and magnetic field killing everything and temperature being far outside the realms of any sort of livable condition in a somewhat believable way. But I can't get past this whole "hundred billion times normal gravity thing" and was wondering if anyone knew any concepts I should explore in search of a solution to this issue. Currently, everyone would simply fall into the sun and the sphere would implode under that amount of gravity. Fantastical concepts are fair play, this is in a science-fantasy world with elder space gods & other good stuff. I'm just trying to figure out gravity nullification concepts for this, if it's even possible.

I've already considered several ideas and done a good bit of preliminary research such as standard anti-gravity fields and the concept of rotating at a high speed to counteract the gravity, but nothing showed up on nullifying something with gravity this intense.

**I'm looking for suggestions on ways to explain the idea of nullifying the gravity of a neutron star in a semi-believable way.**

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand this community.

Comment: *"I want to work in as I plan on detailing much of the land masses (...) So I'm kicking around the idea of using a neutron, pulsar, or magnetar as the size of those work perfectly for what I have planned"* you know that stars are fluid and hot enough on their surfaces to melt iron, right?

Comment: Yes, I've already come up with something to explain that. I'm simply focused on the gravity aspect currently.

Comment: @RyanBraden -- It might help if you made mention of the resources you checked when doing your prior research. No sense in reinventing the wheel if you've already bounced down that road!

Comment: @elemtilas I'll do that! I just googled some basic ways to nullify gravity but all it accommodated for was small amounts, nothing on the level of what I'm working on.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime definitely not exist *on* the star, they would live on the inside of the dyson sphere as a sort of inverted world type concept. I've created a method to negate the heat, radiation, and magnetism but I really am at a loss as to answer "Why/how do they not all fall into the sun, or the dyson sphere implode from the ~200 billion times earth's gravity".

Comment: @RyanBraden -- Great! As much as Stack Exchange is a resource for you to get your questions answered, it's also a resource and archive for future visitors who might have a similar question or issue. Mentioning the avenues of research you've already done may help those geopoets as yet unborn in their quest for the awesomeness of a dyson sphere world!

Comment: You should revise your physics. A Dyson sphere does not exert any gravity in its inside (shell theorem), and on the outside the gravity may be less than Earth's.

Comment: @Renan what do you mean?

Comment: @Aethenosity I looked it up shortly after receiving OP's response to my comment.  What I fail to see is how the density of a star has any relevance to a dyson sphere with an arbitrary radius.

Comment: @RyanBraden Renan already mentioned it. It's the [shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). When a physical body is inside a hollow sphere, the sphere does not exert any gravitational force on that body. That means, if you nullify the gravity of your star, people will just float in a gravity free space inside the sphere. And if you don't, they just fall into your star and die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been pretty well covered in the comments on your question by @Renan and @Otto Abnormalverbraucher, so credit where credit is due, but I thought it deserved its own answer.

**Net gravitational force in a spherical shell is 0**

This is a well established [concept](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/sphshell2.html) in physics.  At any point inside a spherical shell (which your Dyson sphere is), one will feel no gravitational attraction to the inner surface of the shell.

**Give it a whirl**

One way to simulate gravity inside the Dyson sphere is to spin it to create centrifugal "force."  This will create a sensation of gravity towards the inner surface.  The simulated gravity will be weakest where the axis of rotation meets the Dyson sphere (poles), and strongest at points furthers from the axis of rotation (equator).

**Sharing space**

If you want gravity in your inverted world you will need spin (presuming you don't handwave this).  If you also share space in the Dyson sphere with a neutron star, you can counteract the gravity of the star by increasing the spin to counter that.  Note that you will have major differences across the inner surface.  If traveling from the "equator" (where gravity is outward towards the Dyson sphere) towards the "poles" (where gravity is inward towards the neutron star), one would eventually reach a point where the gravity shifts from outward to inward and fall into the star.

Comment: Not gonna lie I made this account, and I've already found an answer within spiderman 2's tritium bs stuff, but I'll definitely rely on the concepts you explain here as a jumping off point to expand my knowledge on this. Appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 10):

You want to build a dyson sphere around a neutron star and you want to devise ways to neutralize its strong gravitation. Presumably, because high gravity will make life extremely uncomfortable for the inhabitants of the dyson sphere.

This answer will suggest two things. One, you need to rethink your dyson sphere, but only slightly. Two, forget about gravitational nullification because it's not at all necessary.

Instead of living on the inside of the dyson sphere its inhabitants can live on its outside. If the surface of the dyson sphere is at the correct distance from the surface of the neutron star it will have a surface gravity of one gee. This is same amount of gravity as found on the surface of good old planet Earth. Also, the dyson sphere will act as a shield to radiation and intense magnetic fields surrounding the neutron star.

This type of dyson sphere has been modelled for white dwarf stars. To use a neutron star as the primary gravitating body around which a dyson sphere can be constructed is but a step up.

The relevant paper is [Dyson Spheres around White Dwarfs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04376) (2015). Its authors are Ibrahim Semiz and Salim Ogur. Copies can be downloaded from the link above.

> We point out that Dyson Spheres could also be built around white dwarfs. This type would avoid the need for artificial gravity technology, in contrast to the AU-scale Dyson Spheres. In fact, we show that parameters can be found to build Dyson Spheres suitable --temperature- and gravity-wise-- for human habitation.

Obviously building a dyson sphere a neutron star will technically more difficult to accomplish than building one around a white dwarf. But it is reasonable to assume that technology will advance to the point that doing the same for neutron stars to become feasible.

A neutron star dyson sphere will not need either artificial gravity technology or gravity nullification technology. The dyson sphere only needs to be built at the correct distance from the neutron star where the effective gravity will be one gee.

In conclusion, this answer argues for the proposition that while the querent believes that gravity nullification is necessary for a neutron star dyson star, this isn't needed at all.

Comment: Possibly the most polite ending to a frame challenge answer I’ve ever seen. +1

Comment: @JoeBloggs Nice of you to say. Simply there was, in my opinion, a better alternative, and I was just trying to be helpful. I like the concept and gave it the respect it deserves.

Comment: If it's further away, it's bigger, which negates op's reason for choosing a neutron star.

Comment: I think the point of choosing a Dyson sphere was that OP wanted an inside-out world.

Comment: Yes that is my reasoning, is I want an inside out-world but at the same time I want to avoid having absurdly large landmasses. I do appreciate your answer though! New perspectives are always useful in this kind of thing and I'll be reading the paper you linked so that is much appreciated.

Comment: @Aethenosity We're only talking about a Dyson sphere with radius of 531,262.7 km. This is smaller than one with a radius of 150,000,000 km for one astronomical unit. This answer was a frame challenge, so being contrary will happen.

Comment: @RealSubtle A point not loss on me. It's just that inside of a Dyson sphere surrounding a neutron star isn't a safe or comfortable place to be. Most likely, a very lethal environment.

Comment: @RyanBraden Excellent! I am delighted you are going to read the paper. It's an absolute gold mine of information about Dyson spheres. Highly recommended. You don't need to worry about absurdly large landmasses. On the outside you can have large numbers of reasonably large landmasses & lots & lots of small ones too. You're welcome to stay with your original idea. This was an alternative approach. New perspectives can be extremely useful. Keep your options open & do what you think is best.

Comment: One gee, wow! If you find a suitable binary pair, you could even have a Sun in the sky, and day-night cycle. Spin the sphere just right and you could fine-tune the cycle to 24 hours. I'm getting nostalgic.

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar That's a nice spin on the idea. It would be like living on a really big planet. A quick calculation shows that spinning the sphere for a 24 hour cycle will have a velocity at the equator of 38.64 km/s. This exceeds an escape velocity (at one gee) of 11.2 km/s. My guess is longer days will be safer. Your binary pair idea is a great addition, but may need fine-tuning for safety. Really appreciate your contribution. It has very interesting possibilities. Good one!

Comment: @a4android The binary pair stars already spin around each other,  the rotation would be only to make up the difference to a 24h cycle,  as finding a pair with a cycle exactly that long would be implausible.  I'm glad to contribute to your good idea,  thanks for the kind words.

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar And, of course, you're right! My guess is this would require a close binary pair. Will have to do research into orbital periods of binary stars to see how it would work out. It's too easy to be too close to an idea and not see its other possibilities. I am grateful for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this idea would work too well because tidal forces (difference in gravity with respect to distance) around neutron stars are very strong, so if the Dyson sphere got out of balance the increased gravity on one edge would be catastrophic. If you had some very powerful ion rockets they could maybe ensure stability (can't remember the novel where I first read this idea).